# Getting the logged in username and email in a view

Tags: 7, views, users

Im trying to get the logged in users username and email adress to display in a view is that possible?

Answer (score 6):

Yes. Just create a view with base table of (user). Then add your fields of username and email. Then add a contextual fileter of uid and set a default value for logged in user.

Comment: But if I have a view that is content based(as base table) and I need the username to construct a custom URL. I thought this would be very easy but it gets more complicating all the time.

Comment: Sorry I am confused. Are you saying you have another view and you also want to attach the username a d email of the current user to it?  If so then you are going to have to create two different views and attach one to the other. You are going to have to provide more info about your setup instead of leaving us to guess based on the limited info you provided. Based in your question I took it as you just needed a single view that shows the current users info.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear with the question. I have a content type that is a "organic group" group content.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear with the question. I have a content type that is a "organic group" group content. called "post"

That content type is attached to an organic group. called team.

Than i want to create a view that lists all posts that belong to a organic group. Until now everything is fine.

Now i need the logged in users username and create a custom url like http://hipphopp.com/q="the logged in users name". But I cant get the logged in users username.... That field is not available in the field.

Comment: You won't find that field, because you are using (content) as your base table. These will need to be separate views.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, do you have any suggestions how to manage to make an custom url in drupal where you combine an content from a node with the users information. I think ill start to investigate if its possible to do it in template.php as a hook function. Thank you again Nigel!

Comment: Use a contextual filter in your view then set it to use the uid from the URL then add a menu item in the view such as user/%1/your-url