# Comparing current user email with a field in a content view: is it possible?

Tags: entities, users, views

I have a content view, and want to filter it on `field_email_field == current_user.email`. I know you can [filter on current user](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/22437/39617), and I know you can get user's email if the view was [based on the user table](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/72830/39617). But I want to add the current user's email as a field in the content view, so I can use a `Global: Fields comparison` filter. Is this possible? Or another way to accomplish this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add FILTER CRITERIA in Views Programmatically](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26431/add-filter-criteria-in-views-programmatically)